# collate default ilike queries not performant even in presence of GIN index

Tags: postgresql

I can't get my queries of type `column_name collate "default" ilike 'abc%'` to work efficiently ( run in subsecond) on my postgres 12 table even after using the GIN index.

The problem and how to reproduce the problem :

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE test_policy(
id SERIAL not null PRIMARY KEY, 
policy_number varchar(255) not null COLLATE "english_ci");
```

**insert 10000000 records**

```
insert into test_policy(policy_number) 
select (select prefix || '/' || suffix from 
  (select prefix from (select string_agg(x, '') from (select     
    start_arr[ 1 + ( (random() * 100)::int) % 13] from (select 
    '{AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,KL,MN,OP,QR,ST,UV,WX,YZ}'::text[] as start_arr)    
     sy, generate_series(1, 3 + (0*generator)) as g)as str2(x)) as 
     s(prefix)) as pre(prefix), (select suffix from (select n[1 + 
    (random() * 100)::int % 10] from (select '{00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 
     05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10}'::text[]) as num(n)) as s(suffix)) as    
    suf(suffix)
) FROM generate_series (1,10000000) as generator 
on conflict do nothing;
```

**Create GIN index**

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_policy_number ON test_policy USING gin (policy_number gin_trgm_ops);
```

Analyse the below query and you will see no index is picked and the run time is ~2.5 second. I would like to know why  and how can I make this query to pick up index. I have lot of tables which are of the mentioned style and the query uses `COLLATE "default" ilike` .

```
explain analyse select count(id) from test_policy where policy_number  COLLATE "default" ilike 'EFWXMN%';
```

**Output**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=107139.59..107139.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2512.638..2517.028 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=107139.38..107139.59 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=2512.318..2517.007 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=106139.38..106139.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2484.685..2484.686 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test_policy  (cost=0.00..106138.33 rows=417 width=4) (actual time=11.753..2483.982 rows=1489 loops=3)
                    Filter: ((policy_number)::text ~~* 'EFWXMN%'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3331844
Planning Time: 0.424 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 17
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 5.328 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.073 ms, Emission 25.693 ms, Total 34.094 ms
Execution Time: 2520.419 ms
```

**My approach of optimizing query**

However, if I alter the column : policy_number of the table as :

```
ALTER TABLE test_policy
ALTER COLUMN policy_number TYPE varchar  ;
```

and run the similar query again you will notice the trgm_idx_policy_number is being used and run time is ~100 ms .

```
explain analyse select count(id) from test_policy where policy_number ilike 'EFWXMN%';
```

**output**

```
Aggregate  (cost=10371.96..10371.97 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=49.658..49.660 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_policy  (cost=124.80..10363.96 rows=3200 width=4) (actual time=34.038..49.203 rows=4395 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((policy_number)::text ~~* 'EFWXMN%'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=4209
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_policy_number  (cost=0.00..124.00 rows=3200 width=0) (actual time=33.598..33.598 rows=4395 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((policy_number)::text ~~* 'EFWXMN%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.134 ms
Execution Time: 49.814 ms
```

Can you please explain why the gin index was used this time and the run time is sub second?

Comment: You've run the explain analyse, but I think you forgot to post the output.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thanks! I have updated the question with the explain plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index and your query must have the same COLLATE.

Try this index and check explain again:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_policy_number_default ON test_policy
    USING gin (policy_number COLLATE "default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

In your ALTER TABLE statement you remove the collate, that's why it's using the default. Just like the default that is used in your query.